# UiAutomator firing events twice (like onPressKeycode, onPressEnter)?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm using code like

```
uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

And my application is consistently firing two events. I can tell since, the enter key is linked to a service, and that service is being called twice.

I've looked in the code (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-sdk-support_r11/uiautomator/library/src/com/android/uiautomator/core/InteractionController.java) and it comes down to this code:

```
public boolean sendKey(int keyCode, int metaState) {
    ...
    KeyEvent downEvent = KeyEvent.obtain(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            keyCode, 0, metaState, KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, 0,
            InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD, null);
    if (injectEventSync(downEvent)) {
        KeyEvent upEvent = KeyEvent.obtain(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                keyCode, 0, metaState, KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, 0,
                InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD, null);
        if(injectEventSync(upEvent)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which from the looks of it means my KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER keycode is being sent to the device twice, once for action_up and once for action_down.

Does anyone know a way around this, experienced similar problems, can confirm my logic in the above is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know much about your application, i will suggest few workaround that I have used or thought of using to fix unexpacted UiAutomator results:

1. instead of using presskeycode, click on a button on screen - if softkeyboard is up you can click on coordinates of enter key - not a clean way but it is a stable workaround.
2. change your service to ignore any request that are too close to one onther. for example if you get two request within 200 ms or even 1 sec, just accept first one.

Comment: To be honest, I abandoned UI Automator in favour of Espresso a while back. I can't remember if I did fix this or not, yet I did do:
if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) { ... } at some point. I'm not marking the answer as resolved since I can't verify it anymore, but thanks nonetheless - have an upvote.